# Circulation of a vector field, why the definition given in Feynman Lectures on Physics is true?

Tags: integration, vector-fields

In the third chapter of Electormagnetism, R.P.Feynman teach the basics of vectoriel integral calculus and I'm stuck in the formula $(3.30)$ give as a definition, but I don't understand why if it works for $C$ it must for $C_t$?

[here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_03.html#Ch3-S5)

> $$\oint_{\Gamma} C\cdot\mathrm{d}s\stackrel{?}{=}\oint_{\Gamma} C_t\mathrm{d}s$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physically, the integral of a vector field $C$ around a closed curve $\Gamma$ represents the work done by $C$ on a point particle that traces $\Gamma$. The work depends only on the tangential component of the field along the curve, i.e., on $C_{t}$; that is, the total work is equal to the work done by the tangential component.

In other words, at each point of $\Gamma$ decompose $C$ into tangential and normal components, say $C = C_{t} + C_{n}$. The work done in moving a point particle an infinitesimal displacement along $\Gamma$ is "all done by $C_{t}$".

Comment: And mathematically? How things work to be sure the formula is exact?

Comment: Parametrize $\Gamma$ by a piecewise-smooth path $\gamma$. At each point $$C \cdot \gamma' = (C_{t} + C_{n}) \cdot \gamma' = C_{t} \cdot \gamma'$$by definition of "decomposition into tangential and normal components. :)